# How to get the time on bag file?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to graph robot's distance from a particular point over time. I have a bag file, and wondering if I can get the duration in the bag file. For instance, if I play a x.bag file, I have the following information:

[PAUSED]   Bag Time: 1346096057.781698   Duration: 1.680327 / 19.253778

Is there a way to get that duration in a code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42795/how-to-get-the-time-on-bag-file?/) by [bkim](https://answers.ros.org/users/3018/bkim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-09-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the command line, use [rosbag info](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline#info).

There is also a [code API](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) for both C++ and Python.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1